# MySQL column flattened to string

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to avoid passing two separate MySQL (version 5.6.37) queries, and using transactions. I think this can be done in a single query, but I need to know where I'm going wrong.

If I use this query:

```
SELECT titles.t_id,title,cover,pageData.pageNum 
FROM titles 
    JOIN biblio     ON titles.t_id = biblio 
    JOIN pageData   ON biblio.t_id = pageData.t_id 
WHERE titles.t_id = '1';
```

It successfully returns a result with three columns of redundant data, and only one column of new data (p_id):

```
t_id | title                |  cover    | pageNum
1    | The Art of the Deal  |  32.jpg   | 1
1    | The Art of the Deal  |  32.jpg   | 2
1    | The Art of the Deal  |  32.jpg   | 3
1    | The Art of the Deal  |  32.jpg   | 4
1    | The Art of the Deal  |  32.jpg   | 5
```

*I think* there is a way to modify the query so that the new data in the pageNum column is flattened into a single result (i.e. converted from integer values to a delimited string), like this:

```
t_id | title                |  cover    | p_id
1    | The Art of the Deal  |  32.jpg   | 1,2,3,4,5
```

I have been experimenting with a sub-SELECT within the SELECT, but I have consistent syntax errors. **Is there a way to combine these two queries below to get the above result?**

```
SELECT titles.t_id,title,cover 
FROM titles 
    JOIN biblio     ON titles.t_id = biblio 
WHERE titles.t_id = '1';
```

and

```
SELECT pageData.pageNum FROM pageData WHERE pageData.t_id = '1'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result you need can be easily accomplished using the MySQL function [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat).
In order to produce a valid SQL query and get the results you expect, you also need to add a [`GROUP BY` clause](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html) to the query and put in it all the other columns that appear in the `SELECT` clause:

```
SELECT titles.t_id, title, cover, GROUP_CONCAT(pageData.pageNum) AS p_id
FROM titles 
    JOIN biblio     ON titles.t_id = biblio 
    JOIN pageData   ON biblio.t_id = pageData.t_id 
WHERE titles.t_id = '1'
GROUP BY titles.t_id, title, cover
```

Comment: All great answers. This one explains it the best. Thanks much, everyone.

Answer (score 3):

You can use GROUP_CONCAT in combination with GROUP BY for that.

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = @@max_allowed_packet

SELECT
    titles.t_id
  , title,cover
  , GROUP_CONCAT(pageData.pageNum) AS p_id 
FROM titles 
    JOIN biblio     ON titles.t_id = biblio 
    JOIN pageData   ON biblio.t_id = pageData.t_id 
WHERE titles.t_id = '1'
GROUP BY
   t_id
 , title
 , cover
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `GROUP_CONCAT` function. Also assuming you meant `JOIN biblio ON titles.t_id = biblio.t_id`

```
SELECT t.t_id, title, cover, GROUP_CONCAT(pageData.pageNum) AS pageNum
FROM titles t
JOIN biblio b ON t.t_id = b.t_id 
JOIN pageData p ON b.t_id = p.t_id
WHERE t.t_id = '1'
GROUP BY t.t_id, title, cover
```